# Allow touch area of button in React Native to extend into status bar (ios)

Tags: react-native

I have a back button (using TouchableOpacity) in the top left of my screen. I want to allow its hit area to extend up into the status bar as that's what other apps seem to do and it's easy to accidentally hit the button a little too high touching the status bar just above instead and making the app feel unresponsive.

I've got it's area to extend up behind the status bar but the status bar still seems to grab touch events. Is there a way of making it not do that (at least on the left hand side, I'd still like the "touch to go to top" stuff to work when you touch it elsewhere)?

Comment: Are you wanting the StatusBar to remain visible, or have the button overlap it?

Comment: I'd like the status bar to remain visible

Answer (score 0):

The `UINavigationBar` is a `UIWindow` (not a `UIView`), which is above the `UIWindow` you are acting in. Thus it is not possible to present `UIViews` from your `UIWindow`.

What you can do is to add transparent `UIBarButtonItem` additionally to your button, triggering the same action:

```
var button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target:  action: #selector(yourAction(_:)))
button.tintColor = UIColor.clear
navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button
```